# How to prevent php script number value getting negative

Tags: php

I found a very useful script on the internet. Anyway I don't want it to go below 0. So it won't showing negative numbers. Also I want that when the number increases, it can increase until a value. For example, I don't want the number to be more than 20 and less than 0.

How can I do that?

The script is this

```html
<?php 
// gets current value 
if(isset($_POST['output'])){ 
    $value = $_POST['output']; 
} else { 
    $value = 0; 
} 
if($_POST['Add']){ 
    // opens the file for reading 
    $read = fopen("file.txt", 'r'); 
    // stores the file as variable cNumAdd 
    $cNumAdd = fread($read, 512); 
    // closes file 
    fclose($read); 
     
    // opens file again 
    $write = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); 
    // adds 1 to the data on the file 
    $cNumAdd = $cNumAdd + 1; 
    // writes the data into the file 
    fwrite($write, $cNumAdd); 
    // closes file 
    fclose($write); 
} 
// comments are the same as above except for subtracting 1 from file 
if($_POST['Remove']){ 
    $read = fopen("file.txt", 'r'); 
    $cNumRemove = fread($read, 512); 
    fclose($read); 
     
    $write = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); 
    $cNumRemove = $cNumRemove - 1; 
    fwrite($write, $cNumRemove); 
    fclose($write); 
} 
?> 


<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
<input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add Career">  
<input type="submit" name="Remove" value="Remove Career">  
<input type="text" name="output" value="<?php include("file.txt"); ?> "> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

```
// opens file again 
$write = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); 
// adds 1 to the data on the file 
$cNumAdd = $cNumAdd + 1; 
// writes the data into the file 
if($cNumRemove > 20) $cNumRemove = 20;
fwrite($write, $cNumAdd); 
// closes file 
fclose($write); 
} 
// comments are the same as above except for subtracting 1 from file 
if($_POST['Remove']){ 
$read = fopen("file.txt", 'r'); 
$cNumRemove = fread($read, 512); 
fclose($read); 

$write = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); 
$cNumRemove = $cNumRemove - 1; 
if($cNumRemove < 0) $cNumRemove = 0;
fwrite($write, $cNumRemove); 
fclose($write); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: code it's okay but I changed this line : if($cNumRemove > 20) $cNumRemove = 20;
with these one : if($cNumAdd > 20) $cNumAdd = 20;

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply compare the number to 0 and 20. If above 20, manually set it to 20. If below 0, manually set it to 0.

**Example:**

```
$num = (int) $_REQUEST['output'];
if ($num < 0) {
  $num = 0;
} elseif ($num > 20) {
  $num = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think plain IF statements can cut it

```html
<?php 
// gets current value 
if(isset($_POST['output'])){ 
    $value = $_POST['output']; 
} else { 
    $value = 0; 
} 
//min and max definitions
define('MIN', 0);
define('MAX', 20);

if($_POST['Add']){ 
    // opens the file for reading 
    $read = fopen("file.txt", 'r'); 
    // stores the file as variable cNumAdd 
    $cNumAdd = fread($read, 512); 
    // closes file 
    fclose($read); 
    
    if($cNumAdd + 1 <= MAX){
    // opens file again 
    $write = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); 
    // adds 1 to the data on the file 
    $cNumAdd = $cNumAdd + 1; 
    // writes the data into the file 
    fwrite($write, $cNumAdd); 
    // closes file 
    fclose($write);
   }
} 
// comments are the same as above except for subtracting 1 from file 
if($_POST['Remove']){ 
    $read = fopen("file.txt", 'r'); 
    $cNumRemove = fread($read, 512); 
    fclose($read); 
    
    if($cNumRemove - 1 >= MIN){
    $write = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); 
    $cNumRemove = $cNumRemove - 1; 
    fwrite($write, $cNumRemove); 
    fclose($write);
    }
} 
?> 


<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
<input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add Career">  
<input type="submit" name="Remove" value="Remove Career">  
<input type="text" name="output" value="<?php include("file.txt"); ?> "> 
</form>
```